# Flink Kafka bounded DataStream is not commiting offset to Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am writing a pipeline where I have to dump `Kafka` data to `S3` every day.

The amount of data is very low (less than 1 million records per day, and the size is 1 KB). Because of this, I want to run this pipeline only once a day.

It will consume data from the last committed offset until the latest offset and write the parquet file to S3.

But when I am running the Flink pipeline in bounded streaming, sometimes it commits the offset for one partition only, or sometimes it doesn't even commit the offset for any of the partitions.

```
Kafka Topic Partitions: 3
Kafka Topic Replication: 1
Java: 11
Flink: 1.17
```

But as per logs, it is committing offsets for all partitions:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=flink-batch-test-2-1, groupId=flink-batch-test-2] Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {my-topic-name-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7907, leaderEpoch=6, metadata=''}}
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=flink-batch-test-2-0, groupId=flink-batch-test-2] Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {my-topic-name-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=45198, leaderEpoch=4, metadata=''}} 
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=flink-batch-test-2-2, groupId=flink-batch-test-2] Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {my-topic-name-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7791, leaderEpoch=2, metadata=''}}  
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher          [] - [Consumer clientId=flink-batch-test-2-0, groupId=flink-batch-test-2] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition my-topic-name-0 at position FetchPosition{offset=45198, offsetEpoch=Optional[4], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[prefix2.mycluster.com:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], epoch=4}} to node prefix2.mycluster.com:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)  
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher          [] - [Consumer clientId=flink-batch-test-2-1, groupId=flink-batch-test-2] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition my-topic-name-1 at position FetchPosition{offset=7907, offsetEpoch=Optional[6], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[prefix3.mycluster.com:9092 (id: 1004 rack: null)], epoch=6}} to node prefix3.mycluster.com:9092 (id: 1004 rack: null) 
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher          [] - [Consumer clientId=flink-batch-test-2-2, groupId=flink-batch-test-2] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition my-topic-name-2 at position FetchPosition{offset=7791, offsetEpoch=Optional[2], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[prefix1.mycluster.com:9092 (id: 1002 rack: null)], epoch=2}} to node prefix1.mycluster.com:9092 (id: 1002 rack: null)  
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=flink-batch-test-2-2, groupId=flink-batch-test-2] Committed offset 7791 for partition my-topic-name-2
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=flink-batch-test-2-1, groupId=flink-batch-test-2] Committed offset 7907 for partition my-topic-name-1 
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=flink-batch-test-2-0, groupId=flink-batch-test-2] Committed offset 45198 for partition my-topic-name-0
```

Sharing my code:

```
package org.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetResetStrategy;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.RuntimeExecutionMode;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.PrintSinkFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.initializer.OffsetsInitializer;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.deserializer.KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        environment.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);

        System.out.println(environment);

        DataStream<String> srcStream
                = environment.fromSource(getKafkaSource(),
                        WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source")
                .name("kafka source")
                .uid("kafka source")
                .setParallelism(1);

        srcStream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String map(String data) throws Exception {
                return data;
            }
        }).name("Transformation");

        srcStream.addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>()).name("Print Sink");


        environment.execute("test");

        environment.close();

    }

    public static KafkaSource<String> getKafkaSource(){

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");

        return KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("prefix1.mycluster.com:9092,prefix2.mycluster.com:9092,prefix3.mycluster.com:9092,prefix4.mycluster.com:9092")
                .setTopics("my-topic-name")
                .setGroupId("flink-batch-test-2")
                .setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.valueOnly(StringDeserializer.class))
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST))
                .setProperties(prop)
                .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: to check committed offset I am using `kafka-lenses`.

Comment: Why use Flink at all? Kafka Connect or Secor both write Parquet to S3 from Kafka. Also, the code you've shown doesn't write to S3

Comment: I want to use `Flink` because we are already using it for all other pipelines. `Kafka Connect` or `Secor` are both good options, but they will increase the tech stack. And regarding the `S3 Parquet Sink`, I am still writing the code and got stuck with `Kafka commits`.

Comment: Offset Commits are automatic, unless you explicitly disable them (which you haven't)

Comment: but for some reason it is not Commit offsets.